# Pass in different container types

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to define a container for a whole bunch of classes as some parts of the code will make more sense with different containers. For example, I might use a Set in some places and a List in others.

I tried to do:

```
public class AllModes<T> {

   private T<Car> car;
   private T<Boat> boat;
   private T<Train> train;
   private T<Plane> plane;
   ...
}
```

But I get the error I get is "The type T is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Car>"

The reason I'm defining these in multiple variables and not a single HashSet based on a superclass is I want to have get methods that return the correct types to avoid consumers of this class needing to cast down everywhere as each object has its own distinct fields.

Comment: Just use `Collection<Car>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter `T` is uselss in your example. Just use one `Collection` to store all required objects.

```
class AllModes {
    private List<Car> cars;
    private List<Boat> boats;
    private List<Train> trains;
    private List<Plane> plain;
}
```

In case you want to select specific collection type - this is quire easy and safe, when you have only one collection in `AllModes`. But you have 4 different types. I think you can use approach with provided `Supplier`:

```
class AllModes {

    private final Collection<Car> cars;
    private final Collection<Boat> boats;
    private final Collection<Train> trains;
    private final Collection<Plane> plain;

    public AllModes(Supplier<Collection<?>> supplier) {
        cars = (Collection<Car>)supplier.get();
        boats = (Collection<Boat>)supplier.get();
        trains = (Collection<Train>)supplier.get();
        plain = (Collection<Plane>)supplier.get();
    }
}
```

And client code will be look like:

```
AllModes modesWithSet = new AllModes(HashSet::new);
AllModes modesWithList = new AllModes(ArrayList::new);
```